# Where does Elsewords fit in the Batwoman timeline?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, batwoman-2019

Generally the Arrowverse shows take place in roughly airdate order, but that doesn't make sense for *Batwoman* and I'm having trouble placing it.

In "Elseworlds", Batwoman has a red wig and full bat suit, which she doesn't get until *Batwoman* episode 3. She doesn't even know who Batman is prior to *Batwoman* episode 1.

There is some reality-rewriting in "Elseworlds", but Kate recognizes Kara in "Crisis of Infinite Earths Part One", so her part of "Elseworlds" doesn't appear to have changed.

*Batwoman* has had only eight episodes so far, and there don't appear to be any long timeskips between episodes, but Kara refers to the events of "Elseworlds" as "last year" at the end of "Crisis of Infinite Earths Part Two".

Prior to "Crisis of Infinite Earths" I thought the entire first season of *Batwoman* would take place before "Elseworlds", but at the end of "Crisis of Infinite Earths Part Two", Kate refers to the events of *Batwoman* episode 8 as if they were recent.

Is there any way of placing the episodes of *Batwoman* in the rest of the Arrowverse timeline that makes sense?

Comment: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/105603/where-does-elseworlds-fit-into-batwoman-chronology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own answer from [Movies & TV Stackexchange](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/105604/1190)

After Batwoman S01E04 and before S01E05.

From [Caroline Dries](https://twitter.com/carolinedries/status/1188626252174770176?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1188626252174770176&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fscreenrant.com%2Fbatwoman-tv-show-episode-4-elseworlds-timeline%2F)'s tweet

> After 104 we are officially caught up to Elseworlds!  #batwoman

Later [Russ Burlingame](https://twitter.com/russburlingame/status/1189385064347525120) continued:

> Because the writers wanted to show Kate's origin story, they had to go back to before she was Batwoman, which required some catching-up in the first few episodes. Instead of it being a week between episodes, chronologically speaking, these early episodes have had more time pass.

Also from [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/batwoman-elseworlds-reference/) from 5th epsiode

> Last week, Batwoman showrunner Caroline Dries revealed the show had caught up to "Elseworlds" in the Arrowverse timeline. Now, the show has dropped an explicit reference to last year's crossover event, which introduced Kate Kane to the DCTV universe.
>
> Inthat epsiode Luke is referring to the Flash and Green Arrow's altercation with Dr. John Deegan, which took place at Arkham Asylum.